# Does Graphology Have Any Basis In Judaism?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, science, writing-printing, middos-character-traits

Graphology is the theory/science that one's middos can be deduced from one's handwriting.

Is there any source for such ideas from the rishonim or earlier?

Comment: Relevant but I cannot vouch for the authenticity one way or another. http://m.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2753603/jewish/Meet-Mr-Handwriting-Guy.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are modern-day kabbalists and "holy men" who claim to do such things. I'm not aware of any source for this (nor against it either, for that matter) in classical Jewish literature.

Comment: We don't know you that we should value your opinion all that much. Are you such an expert that your not knowing of a source should be meaningful to us? What places did you check unsuccessfully for a source? Try backing up your claims with verifiable sources to increase the value of your posts.